# Multiple binders configuration on Spring Cloud Stream not working from version Hoxton.SR4

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a microservice working properly on Spring Boot v2.2.7 and Spring Cloud vHoxton.SR3 over OpenJdk 1.8. This microservice retrieves JSON messages from a provider via a public RabbitMQ server, processes them and finally produces a JSON message that is published into an internal RabbitMQ server via Spring Cloud Stream.

It has been working fine since version Hoxton.SR1 but when I tried to update Spring Cloud to Hoxton.SR4 I got the following error (I enabled debug mode on Spring Boot):

```
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.stream-output.producer.routing-key-expression' to org.springframework.expression.Expression
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:364)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:452)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:572)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:558)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$400(Binder.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:452)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:572)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:558)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$400(Binder.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$null$1(Binder.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withSource(Binder.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$900(Binder.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindAggregate$2(Binder.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.AggregateElementBinder.bind(AggregateElementBinder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.MapBinder$EntryBinder.lambda$bindEntries$0(MapBinder.java:157)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.MapBinder$EntryBinder.bindEntries(MapBinder.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.MapBinder.bindAggregate(MapBinder.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.AggregateBinder.bind(AggregateBinder.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindAggregate$3(Binder.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:572)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$100(Binder.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindAggregate(Binder.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:376)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:452)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:572)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:558)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$400(Binder.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:201)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:139)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:362)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:257)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at gg.eurasiasports.platform.price.merger.PriceMergerApplication.main(PriceMergerApplication.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.expression.Expression]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$CompositeConversionService.convert(BindConverter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindProperty(Binder.java:435)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:380)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
    ... 108 common frames omitted

2020-06-02 17:49:07.669 ERROR [price-merger-service,,,] 22896 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.stream-output.producer.routing-key-expression' to org.springframework.expression.Expression:

    Property: spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.stream-output.producer.routing-key-expression
    Value: headers['routingKey']
    Origin: "spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.stream-output.producer.routing-key-expression" from property source "commandLineArgs"
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.expression.Expression]

Action:

Update your application's configuration

2020-06-02 17:49:07.669  WARN [price-merger-service,,,] 22896 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.config.RabbitMessageChannelBinderConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitExtendedBindingProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.cloud.stream.rabbit-org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.properties.RabbitExtendedBindingProperties': Could not bind properties to 'RabbitExtendedBindingProperties' : prefix=spring.cloud.stream.rabbit, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.stream-output.producer.routing-key-expression' to org.springframework.expression.Expression
```

This is the Spring Cloud configuration portion on Spring Boot's application.properties file:

```
#
# RabbitMQ Transport layer
#
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit-transport-layer.environment.spring.rabbitmq.addresses=somehost:5672
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit-transport-layer.environment.spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=test
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit-transport-layer.environment.spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit-transport-layer.environment.spring.rabbitmq.password=pass

spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit-transport-layer.type=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit-transport-layer.environment.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.stream-output.producer.exchange-type=topic
spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit-transport-layer.environment.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.stream-output.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routingKey']

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.stream-output.destination=price-merger-out-price-mixer-in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.stream-output.group=local
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.stream-output.binder=rabbit-transport-layer

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.source-price-input.destination=price-sync-out-price-merger-in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.source-price-input.group=local
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.source-price-input.binder=rabbit-transport-layer
```

I have also tried Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR5 and it does not work either but behaviour is different: Spring Boot gets stuck when I start it up, waiting for something relating to RabbitMQ configuration, I would say.

If I comment the line where I set the *routing-key-expression* out, the application starts fine with Hoxton.SR4 but the generated routing key is not the one I want to use which is set by the application in the header *routingKey*.

It seems that my configuration is conflicting with something introduced on version Hoxton.SR4 but I can not find the reason. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I just ran this application which uses `Hoxton.SR4` and didn't get the error you are getting. Although this app doesn't use `routing-key-expression`, in the producer config it uses `partition-key-expression` which needs that SpEL expression converter. Could you compare your dependencies with these samples? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/partitioning-samples/rabbit-partitioning

Comment: I checked the dependencies and spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:3.0.4.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter:2.2.7.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.7.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.2.7.RELEASE and spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.7.RELEASE  are in the effective POM.

Comment: @sobychacko I also ran the sample and worked fine so I added ```spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.* info (addresses, username, password , virtual-host)``` and the sample worked fine too.
But when I added ```spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.generate-out-0.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routingKey']``` to application.yml file of partitioning-producer-sample-rabbit, the unit test was not able to load the context because of the ConverterNotFoundException error we are talking about.

Comment: So, this could be something specific to the `routing-key-expression`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. I would say the expression is okay so do you have any idea what the problem could be, why a converter for the routing key expression can not be found?

Comment: I have seen an issue has already been opened with _spring-cloud-stream_: [No converter found capable of converting...](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1979)

Comment: Ok. We will take a look.